# Is it possible to enable zombies and scribble for an archive ad-hoc build?

Tags: ios, xcode

I want to distribute an app to testers via an archive/ad-hoc build, however in the Edit Scheme dialog the Diagnostics tag that enables Zombies and Scribble etc. is not available for the Archive build step, its only available within the Run step.

Is it therefore possible to create and distribute a build with these things enabled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those settings are not built into the app, these are just options specified at the time the app is launched. On Mac OS X these can be specified by setting environment variables before starting the app. For iOS apps there is no way to specify these options if you don’t start the app from inside Xcode AFAIK.